# Access to XMLHttpRequest.statusText will cause exception when it fails?

Tags: jquery, ajax, exception, status

```
$.ajax(error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
             { XMLHttpRequest.statusText })
```

Did someone also met this problem?

**EDIT**

I'm using Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/2008091620 Firefox/3.0.2

Comment: more info please. for instance, a browser would be nice.

Comment: I'm using Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/2008091620 Firefox/3.0.2

Comment: You can somehow make the error handler be called,it's 100% sure to cause exception in my browser.

Comment: btw, edit your question with that type of info. so it's not the first thing i thought of. what is the error in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing **XMLHttpRequest** to something like '**e**'. Might just be a naming conflict?
Also, are you actually making a valid ajax call?

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: "/file/location.php", 
    data: "param"+value,
    error: function(e){
        alert(e.responseText);
    }
    success: function(data) { alert(data); }
});
```

Comment: I changed it to 'xhr',but still happens.

Answer (score 0):

What is your exception?

The statusText Property
The statusText attribute represents the HTTP status code text and is also available only when the readyState value is 3 or 4. Attempting to access the statusText property for other readyState values raises an exception.

Firefox also throws exception if there was a lower level network issue with the request that caused the error. NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE